# Webscraping with cheerio nodeJS

Tags: node.js, cheerio

I'm trying to scrape one webpage to try some skills with **cheerio** and I'm not able to do it. I'm using axios to make the http **request**.

scrape.js

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const axios = require('axios');

async function iniciar() {
    axios.get('https://www.idealo.es/precios/4102124/the-north-face-men-s-mcmurdo-parka-tnf-black.html').then( res => {
        var price = [];
        const $ = cheerio.load(res.data);

        $('span.oopStage-variantThumbnailsFromPrice').each( (index, element) => {
            const name = $(element).first().text()
            price.push(name)
        })
        console.log(price);
    })
}

module.exports = {
    iniciar
};
```

main.js

```
const scrape = require('./assets/scrape');
scrape.iniciar()
```

It is allways returning a empty value.

```
<strong>
 <span class="oopStage-variantThumbnailsFromText">desde</span>
 <span class="oopStage-variantThumbnailsFromPrice">294,99&nbsp;€</span>
</strong>
```

Any idea.

Comment: What's the error message? You got to be specific about your problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this is not working for you is that the html generated by your desired page is dynamic, it's generated on the client side by JavaScript code.

We can still scrape the data, but we must use something like [Puppeteer](https://pptr.dev/) (Zombie.js or another headless browser might work too.) I'll use Puppeteer for this example though.

We load the page you wish, then parse the html in much the same way you were before.

I'm also using [user-agents](https://www.npmjs.com/package/user-agents) to generate a random user-agent to avoid a Captcha request.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const userAgent = require('user-agents');

async function getDynamicPageHtml(url) {
    try {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.setUserAgent(userAgent.toString());

        await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });
        const html = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('*').outerHTML);

        await browser.close();
        return html;
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return null;
    }
}

async function iniciar() {
    const html = await getDynamicPageHtml('https://www.idealo.es/precios/4102124/the-north-face-men-s-mcmurdo-parka-tnf-black.html');
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);
    const price = $('span.oopStage-variantThumbnailsFromPrice').map( (index, element) => {
        return $(element).first().text().trim();
    }).toArray();
    console.log("iniciar: price:", price);
    return price;  
}

module.exports = {
    iniciar
};
```

I'm getting the below output when I call iniciar:

```
iniciar: price: [ '294,99 €' ]
```